# Route only some traffic through different VPNs

Tags: vpn, split-tunneling

In my work, I have quite a few different external networks that I need to access from time to time via VPN. Generally I need to connect to somebody else's managed network to access their Building Management System (BMS) so I am at the mercy of however they set up their network access - this usually involves juggling various assigned logins and having to re-enter the credentials everywhere I go. More annoyingly, they usually require me to login to their VPN (most often through GlobalProtect). These are not my primary work networks, so the restrictions vary and I have to log into the VPN and then back out as soon as I am done so that I am not sending all of the rest of my traffic through the VPN. In a few of these instances, I have run into issues where I can't directly access the internet for troubleshooting while I am connected to the VPN because of their restrictive policies.

Is there a relatively straightforward way to wall off either a separate instance of Chrome or maybe a Windows desktop where only that traffic would be routed through the VPN? I thought that maybe split tunneling might be the answer, but that seemed to miss the mark when I tried to use NordVPN since it would only let me connect to their VPN servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the VPN connections enforce policies where all traffic is forwarded via the VPN. This is for security reasons.

Therefore you should run the VPN on separate computer, or a virtual machine. This way only that computer / virtual machine traffic goes via the VPN.

Comment: Ultimately you were right.  Split-tunneling as advertised was not the same as what I was trying to use it for.  The best solution for the problem that I was having was, as you suggested, a virtual machine that had its own dedicated VPN connection.